# How to print the node body in a custom block?

Tags: 8, blocks

I am trying to print the node body in a custom block, but it's not showing up. I'm I doing this correctly?

```
$refer = $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER];
$parsed = parse_url($refer);
$alias = array_pop($parsed);
$dst = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getPathByAlias($alias , $langcode);
$nid = array_pop(explode('/', $dst));
$dest_node = node_load($nid);

$body = $dest_node->get('body')->getValue();
print $body; //have tried other printing methods also but invain
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`$dest_node->get('body')->getValue();`

this will return an array. So,`$body` is an array. 
If you want the Body field values, then get it by accessing the proper index of the `$body` array. i.e **$body[0]['value']**

just replace `print $body;` with `print $body[0]['value'];`

Comment: That's right, `getValue()` gets an array with value, summary and format as keys. To access the body value there is a shorter way: `$body_value = $dest_node->body->value;`